# MongoDb Aggregation Query Slow performance Issue

Tags: mongodb, indexing, nosql, aggregation-framework, query-optimization

```js
db.coll.aggregate([{
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $eq: [{
                        $toString: {
                            "format": "%d/%m/%y",
                            "date": "$valueDate"
                        }
                    },
                    "02/06/2021"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'coll2',
            let: {
                'account': '$accountData',
                'cur': '$currency',
                'valueDate': '$valuDate',
                'transref': '$transrefId',
                'amount': '$amount'
            },
            'pipeline': [{
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        '$and': [{
                                $eq: ['$acc', '$$account']
                            },
                            {
                                $eq: ['$currency', '$$cur']
                            },
                            {
                                $eq: ['$valueDate', '$$valueDate']
                            },
                            {
                                $eq: ['$transref', '$$transref']
                            },
                            {
                                $eq: ['$amount', '$$amount']
                            },
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }],
            as: 'derived'
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "derivied.0": {
                $exists: True
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            BRK_DESCRIPTION: "Partial Match",
            BRK_IND: "P",
            BRK_ID: "_id",
            BRK_CURR: "$curreny",
            BRK_INT_ACC: {
                $arrayElemAt: ["derived.acc", 0]
            },
            BRK_INT_Valuedate: {
                $arrayElemAt: ["derived.valuedate", 0]
            },
        }
    },
    {
        $out: 'temp_coll3'
    }

])
```

I am working on Mongodb aggregation queries it's performance is very slow. I need to generate some insights about my data for that I have used operations like $match, $lookup, $unwind, $match, $project, $out in the same sequence. with in a day this query has to deal with approximately 400k records or more. The collections contains more than 50 millions records. But it's performance is very slow when it comes to the final $out operation.

Index creation:

I have 5 fields - $accout, $amount, $ currency, $date, $referenceId.

Logic - these 4 fields should exactly match with the data in another collection and $referenceId should not match. so I have created an compound index on ($account, $amount, $currency, $date). Does the sequence matter while creating the index. is this the correct index for my query?

Comment: Please don't use Indian words like lakh / lac here. Rest of the world doesn't use or understand them.

Comment: Optimal index definition will depend on how each field is queried.  Can we see a sample query?

Comment: I have added the query.

Comment: did you add the index to both coll1 and coll2 ?